# Error while starting a Cassandra Cluster on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to set up a 3-node cassandra cluster on amazon EC2 instances yet i am having an issue while trying to startup the cluster.
Here are my configuration options:

**Node-1**

- *private-ip* a.a.a.a
- *public-ip* b.b.b.b

**Node-2:**

- *private-ip* c.c.c.c
- *public-ip* d.d.d.d

**Node-3:**

- *private-ip* e.e.e.e
- *public-ip* f.f.f.f

For each node I have chosen both **Node-1** and **Node-2** to be seeds. Therefore on all the cassandra.yaml files i have added the nodes public IPs.

Moreover, for each instance I have set the following properties:

- **listen_address** private-ip
- **broadcast_address** public-ip
- **rpc_address** 0.0.0.0
- **broadcast_rpc_address** public-ip
- **endpoint_snitch** Ec2Snitch
- **auto_bootstrap** false

Yet while trying to initialize the first node, the following exception happens:

```
ERROR [main] 2016-12-26 17:08:55,336 CassandraDaemon.java:654 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.maybeAddOrUpdateKeyspace(StorageService.java:1025) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:903) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:647) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:518) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:310) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:532) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:641) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what you did to resolve this? It would be great to have closure as I am stuck in a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with rpc_address and listen_address as eth0.

We have built cassandra cluster on EC2 nodes with EC2Snitch and with eth0 and it works perfectly.